# How to identify a vine copula?

Tags: copula, marginal-distribution, vine-copula

In the image below is a mixed vine copula composed of 3 copulae, therefore 3 marginals. It shows the 2d marginals and 100 samples of a 3d mixed vine.

[image]

Without being told its a vine copula, how would someone know that it is specifically a vine copula and not just 3 regular copula for 3 different random variables plotted separately?

Optional, guess the marginal distributions, and guess the 3 copula pairs

Comment: Are you literally putting on a contest of guessing models for simulated data, or are you actually just trying to figure out a model for a real dataset? In the latter case, the point isn't to guess that the data "comes from" a vine copula, but that a vine copula is a useful model for that data, even if it doesn't literally come from a vine copula.

Comment: guessing was an optional question. The real question is if there is something in the image that tells the viewer that it is a vine copula. because to me, all i see are three separate copula, nothing about vines

Comment: That's my point, it doesn't matter that it "is" a vine; vines are general and flexible models, and they can work well for data that are not literally simulated from a vine. If you're asking, "how can I tell from these pictures that a vine will work well?", to be honest I don't know that anyone can. That's what goodness of fit tests, information criteria, out of sample testing with multivariate proper scoring rules, etc. are for. I suppose these pictures *do* show that a single copula of the usual families will *not* be sufficiently flexible because of the differences in types of relations.

Comment: my point was that the image *was* generated by vine, that took for inputs the distribution types for the marginals and the copula types. So I just mean, looking at that picture, is it a vine, or a representation of a vine, or not. or is there no hint in the image that it is a vine, and someone could make the "mistake" to say that they only see copulas

Comment: So, a vine copula *is* a copula. There is a single copula that corresponds to every vine. It is just not typically one of the few "named" copulas. Vines are a convenient way to build complicated copulas out of basic bivariate ones. There is no "mistake" in saying that the data in the picture was generated "from a copula".

Comment: thanks, also would like to ask, how the word vine is supposed to represent the idea of a mixture of copulas, since copulas appear to be blobs or mounds. mixing blobs doesn't resonate to me with the idea of thin, branch-like vines. so why that connotation? visually in the figure, i do not see vine-like objects

Comment: They are named after the types of graphs that arise in describing which pairs of variables are modeled by each copula: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vine_copula

Comment: Vine copula models two variables at a time. Hence, there is no restriction on the type of bivariate copula for each pair of variables. Therefore, one can fit different copula for each edge. Hence, some literature called this a mixture of copulas as we do not restrict to one type of copula function.

Comment: For your question, the graph does not show the full vine as it does not include the conditional plot. However, we almost do not care whether this plot came from a vine copula or not. All that we are interested in is how vine copula can best model our data.

Comment: by edge do you mean a marginal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A vine copula is a sequence of bivariate copulas, which is what is shown in the image. The proper depiction of the overall vine requires a graph tree linking the individual bivariate copulas

Comment: @ Develarist : Great answers on Copula questions! I have some questions about this - can I ask them?